# Figuring out memoize from WWDC 2014 - Session 404

Tags: swift, functional-programming, swift3, closures

I'm working through understanding the parameters used in the (simple) version of the memoized fibonacci explained in the [Advanced Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/404/) session (jump to 00:38:00)

In the session the following memoize function is defined (adapted to Swift 3)

```
func memoize<T: Hashable, U>(body: @escaping (T) -> U) -> (T) -> U {
    var memo = Dictionary<T, U>()
    return { x in
        if let q = memo[x] { return q }
        let r = body(x)
        memo[x] = r
        return r
    }
}
```

And it will wrap simple functions, for example:

```
let ntos = memoize {(n: Int) -> String in
    print("Must evaluate something")
    return "\(n)"
}

print(ntos(3))
print(ntos(3))
print(ntos(30))
```

output:

> ```
> Must evaluate something
> 3
> 3
> Must evaluate something
> 30
> ```

The type of ntos is `(Int) -> String` so the `T` in memoize becomes `Int` and `U` becomes `String`.

But for the fibonacci function, the example apple are using is

```
let fibonacci = memoize {
    fibonacci, n in
    n < 2 ? Double(n) : fibonacci(n: n - 1) + fibonacci(n: n - 2)
}
```

Here I'm not sure what types T, and U are adapting? and how the function behaves for the recursive nature? How the closure parameter declaration `fibonacci, n` translate to the type `memoize (T) -> U` body parameter?

Why fibonacci is even in the definition of closure passed to memoize? I assume it's something to do with the idea of curried functions (that was replaced by closures in Swift 3) but the implementation syntax just doesn't clicks for me.

Comment: Possible related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37690663/explanation-for-swift-memoization-call-syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to it a step further and wrote a full fledges [walk through of memoize](https://medium.com/@mvxlr/swift-memoize-walk-through-c5224a558194#.sl4bfon3k)

Comment: Seems like a thorough walk-through, nice work! But note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) here on SO (even if it's your own link, we wont know if it persists in a few years from now); could you possibly quote/highlight some parts from your blog post such that this SO answer answers, at least briefly, the question of this thread? You could refer to your blog post for a more in-detail coverage.